# How to change commit author on gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I making project for my friend but after few commits i see the problem. I thinked if im log in on his account it will be created like him. But it was created my other author(me). Can i change this on gitlab ? If is options to change it without changing data commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+commit+author

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. Clone the repo locally, then use filter branch

```
 git filter-branch --commit-filter 'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "John Doe" ];
  then export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="My Friend"; export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=friend@friends.com;
  fi; git commit-tree "$@"'
```

Comment: @MrSCoder - That command is written correctly and it works.  If you run `git log` you will see the current author name, that must match the `$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`.  As long as you do that, it should work.

Comment: yes i see on log data , i am getting error WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/mybranch' is unchanged, my name same in both user correct one is Xyz Abc miss name xyz abc  both user gitlab username and email are complete different  Currently i want to remove xyz abc user from comments user list